# What is the tone of this line?

Tags: reading, tone, comprehension

I am preparing for an aptitude test and then I came to a question. I need to find the 'tone' of a line that is written below.

*John likes work, it fascinates him! He can sit and look at it for hours.*

I am not sure whether it is good place to ask this type of question. If it's not, please let me know. I will delete this question

Answer: Sarcastic

Thank you in advance.
-Vaibhav

Comment: It's not clear what the appropriate "tone" values are.  And even if you were to supply them it's not clear this question would be on topic- subjective questions based on opinion are not.

Comment: The 'tone' of the second sentence is _sarcastic_ (humorously sarcastic possibly). The first sentence encourages you to think that John would be a hard worker, the second tells you he does nothing productive at all.

Comment: From *The Lexicon of Intentionally Ambiguous Recommendations*: "You should consider yourself lucky if you can this man to work for you."

Comment: This is a quotation from Jerome K Jerome, *Three Men in a Boat*.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds totally sarcastic! The first sentence might not tell it but the second clearly does. The speaker has said that John would just sit and won't do the work assigned to him.